# Unexpected End of Input in Line 1

Tags: javascript, html

Been trying to work on a book exercise and I'm currently creating a multpplier function. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chapter 4, Exercise 1</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var funcNumber = parseInt(prompt("Please Enter Number to multiply:"), 10);
    var funcMultiplier = parseInt(prompt("Start Multiplication from:"), 10);
    var funcEnd = parseInt(prompt("Up to:"), 10);
    var funcResult;


    function multiplesOf(funcNumber, funcMultiplier) {
        for(funcMultiplier;funcMultiplier<=funcEnd;funcMultiplier++){
                funcResult = funcNumber * funcMultiplier;
                return funcResult;
                document.write(funcNumber + "*" + funcMultiplier + "=" + funcResult      + "<br/>");
            }
        }
    }

    function multiplesOf(funcNumber, funcMultiplier)



    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But upon running it in a browser it says " Unexpected end of input" in html:1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line

```
function multiplesOf(funcNumber, funcMultiplier)
```

You're defining a function but without a and that's a syntax error.

If you're trying to call `multiplesOf`, the correct syntaxt would be

```
var result = multiplesOf(funcNumber, funcMultiplier);
```

Some other problems in your code (added comments)

```
function multiplesOf(funcNumber, funcMultiplier) {
    for(funcMultiplier;funcMultiplier<=funcEnd;funcMultiplier++){
            funcResult = funcNumber * funcMultiplier;
            return funcResult; // this stops execution flow, nothing else is executed
            document.write(funcNumber + "*" + funcMultiplier + "=" + funcResult + "<br/>");
        }
    }
} // you missed this
```

Comment: the funny thing is I removed ; intentionally as it also issues an error "Unexpected token ;"

Comment: thanks for the added input regarding the return. I just removed it and everything is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line:

```
function multiplesOf(funcNumber, funcMultiplier)
```

Your code is just declaring that function, which gave the error you saw.

What you want is a function call. Try setting the output of your function to a variable and then working with it.

```
var output = multiplesOf(funcNumber, funcMultiplier);
alert(output);
```

Comment: it's working now, quick question though, why is the function call wrong? I actually had function multiplesOf(funcNumber, funcMultiplier); as my function call but it issued "Unexpected token ;"